# Always showing last users information

Tags: java, spring, session

We developed an ERP in Spring. After deployment a serious problem occurred.

Suppose three user logs in the system:

- Firstly, when Tom (an user) logs in, he finds his own files that he created/saved before then.
- When John (another user) logs in that time, both Tom and John see the files that belong to John.
- After that if Tuf (another user) logs in that time,  all three user see files that belong to Tuf.

In our DAO implement file we have done save or update as follows:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory session;
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("query goes here");
```

Comment: Relevant information is missing, for instance, how user authorization is being handled, what exactly 'see someone's files' means, how that is related to "delete order" posted etc..

Comment: What is the query you are using fetch file information for the user?

Comment: `session.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(orderInfo);` This is used to save or update an order information object.

Comment: To fetch order list
`return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from OrderInfo where membership_no = '"+ membership_no +"'  order by order_id desc").list();`